# Java Reflection: How to pass a method to another so that it can be executed (no interfaces)

Tags: java, reflection

I would like to have a method which can invoke a method that is passed to it. The idea is to retry if there is a dead lock exception, and instead of adding a `try` `catch` to every place I want this, I would rather have a utility that works like `retryExecution(Method method)`. Inside the `retryExecution` method is all the reusable logic to handle retrying deadlocks. I would like to do this without the use of AOP and also without the use of an interface (since I am telling the retryExcution method what the method to invoke is, instead of depending on what the method name is via the interface).

Comment: It's better to have a method called `tryExecution(Runnable)`. Put the code you want to try to execute inside the `run` method of the runnable.

Comment: In case you decide that using an interface is acceptable, you might want to look at the [`Callable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) interface, it might be what you need ;-)

Answer (score 10):

You use an interface.

You use an interface.

You use an interface.

Or you use an abstract class, which is a variation on that theme.

If you refuse to follow the design of the language for solving this problem and 'use an interface', you read the javadoc for `java.lang.reflect` and obtain a `Method` object and pass it around. http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/

The designers of Java considered and rejected callable methods as first class objects (along the lines of, say, C++ or C function values).

Comment: An abstract class wouldn't be that bad. / See also Execute Around idiom.

Comment: Point taken. I meant to discourage java.lang.reflect a lot more than I meant to draw a distinction between interface and abstract class.

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose you have to provide the `Method` instance, the `Object` on which you want to call the method and the needed parameters.

See the [method `invoke` on the documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...%29).

Answer (score 0):

You will of course have to know the name of the method to retry. If you know the method name and have the object, then calling the method is easy.

```
public Object retry(Object objectWithTheMethod, String methodName) {
    try {
        Method method = objectWithTheMethod.getClass().getMethod(methodName);
        return method.invoke(objectWithTheMethod);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
    }
}
```

It gets just a little more complicated if the method requires some parameters. You would then have to specify the parameter classes to getMethod. I.e. if the method requires one String parameter:

```
Method method = objectWithTheMethod.getClass().getMethod(methodName, String.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is easy with **Lambda Expressions**.

1. Upgrade to [Java SE 8](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/lambda/).
2. Write some code using Lambda:

   ```
   int sum = 0;
   list.forEach(#{ e -> sum += e.size(); });
   ```
3. Log into [freenode](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Freenode) and join one of #concatenative, #python, #haskell, or [others](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29#Closure-like_constructs_in_other_languages) and congratulate them on their forward thinking
4. Sell your copy of [SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/) to pay for a victory dinner.